# Put a logo on twitter bootstrap navbar without resizing the navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to put an image (brand logo) on bootstrap's navbar like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="../Content/Images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and keep the navbar height untouched? 
I tried

```
.navbar .brand
{
display: block;
height: 125px;
width: 246px;
padding: 0;
background: url('../Content/Images/logo.png') no-repeat left center;
float:left;
position: absolute;
}
```

and i have good results with the positioning but the links come over the logo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> the links come over the logo

This is caused by the absolute positioning.

**Update** Without resizing the image :

```
.navbar .brand {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

[Demo without resizing image (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MMdrJ/2/)

Comment: I don't want the image to be re-sized. I want not to re-size the container div. Take a look at this logo [link](http://www.skagos.gr/)