# How can I center a brand image with other elements in Bootstrap 3.2's navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[Example http://www.n2media.com/img/header-example.jpg](http://www.n2media.com/img/header-example.jpg)

I'm hoping to have this look when on a large screen but then fall back to the default Bootstrap navbar when on mobile:

[Example2 http://www.n2media.com/img/header-example-mobile.jpg](http://www.n2media.com/img/header-example-mobile.jpg)

I was able to get the logo enlarge by following [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816819/put-a-logo-on-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-without-resizing-the-navbar)

I've also found plenty of ways to get the simple links to be centered.  The one I was using was this:

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

However I haven't been able to get the `navbar-brand` element to center between all of the simple links.  Even if I do, I'm not sure how I can exclude it from the collapsing elements for small screens.

Comment: I did just this the other day but cannot get bootply to fire up so I can retrieve it. If you haven't got this figured out by tomorrow I will try again.

Comment: Here are a few examples on Bootply - http://www.bootply.com/oJI0QzytvR, http://www.bootply.com/Sa1pWiXH9T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use Bootstrap's Responsive Utilities and just stick the logo in two places, you could show/hide the logo depending on screen size like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/oCdrwBp4jqxqRHPqcqGT?p=preview).

In order to horizontally center Bootstrap's nav list items, which are floated by default, you could either wrap the entire list in a relatively positioned div, or remove the floats and apply `display: inline-block`. In the example I've given, I've used the relatively positioned div and then cleared it at the same media breakpoint as when the mobile menu appears because I think it's a bit simpler.

**CSS**

```
#nav-wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
@media (max-width: 769px){
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand img {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #nav-wrapper {
        float: none;
        position: static;
    }
   .navbar-nav {
       position: static;
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I was hoping to avoid duplicating the element but it wasn't a deal breaker for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution may be to duplicate your logo, once in Bootstrap's stock 'Brand' location, and once within the `<li>` elements of your navbar, then use `.hidden-xs` and `.visible-xs` classes to either show or hide it depending on device. Bootply seems to be down so can't show a working DEMO, but this should do it (or get close)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" /></a>
  <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
```