# Adding image to Bootstrap navbar makes it wrong size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I get an image from Steam cdn which is 32x32 and I want to add it to a navbar.

This is the code I currently have for the part of the navbar with the image:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <style type="text/css">
          #login:hover {
            background-color:transparent;
          }
        </style>
          <li class="dropdown" id="login">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle brand" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="pgurl"><img src="http://mysitemyway.com/_shared/images/icons/black/Clock.png"/>Username</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
      </ul>
```

Using that, it makes my navbar do this:
[image]

Using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816819/put-a-logo-on-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-without-resizing-the-navbar) it changes the alignment over the text and image but keeps the navbar the same.

[image]

So really, my question is how can I use that image alongside the text but not ruin the size of the navbar which ruins the hover and active triggers?

[DEMO](http://www.codeply.com/go/y7NOYqD3G0)

Comment: post relevant code / create a demo?

Comment: I tried creating a demo on jsfiddle but it doesn't display how it's shown on  localhost. I can post the full page code if that is any help for you, though.

Comment: I've added a demo link to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `.navbar` is not fixed or `min-height` or `height` and then override it to the height you want using CSS:

Try to find a height which is good both for images and text. If necessary you can move the image around:

```
.navbar {
    height: 40px;
}

.navbar img {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried both of those but none seemed to do the trick. I've added a demo link to the bottom of my post.

Comment: My issue the active nav background doesn't follow the height of the nav once an image is inserted. Using the CSS that you provided, the text doesn't seem aligned and the active navbar overlaps the navbar a little. [See this](http://www.codeply.com/go/y7NOYqD3G0)

Comment: Change your HTML so that `<a><img></a>` and `<a>text</a>` are separate elements with ids and use `position: relative` trick to align them to each other.